# Reloading url page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i'm trying to refresh page every 3 second, the url page change with $_GET variable.
i'm trying to save $_GET var into session and cookie, but get error header has already sent.
how to change url after page reload ?

here my script :
**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$skill =$_SESSION['skill'];

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
        $('#src2').load('monitor.php?skill=<?php echo $skill;?>').fadeIn("slow");
    }, 3000); 
</script>
```

**monitor.php**

```
   <?php
include "conn.php";
session_start();
$_SESSION['skill'] = $_GET['skill'];

if ($_SESSION['skill']=='')
  {
    $a ="bro";
   $_SESSION['skill']=4;}
elseif ($_SESSION['skill']==4){
    $a = "yo";
    $_SESSION['skill']='5';
  }
   elseif ($_SESSION['skill']==5){
    $a = "soo";
  }

?>
```

Comment: You cannot change Header with php after something is already sent. You can use windows.reload (javascript) or some window.location (Javascript)

Comment: Do you echo anything before calling session_start() or set the cookie?

Comment: "i'm trying to save $_GET var into session and cookie" — Not in the code you've shared with us.

Comment: @Quentin update new code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, "headers already sent" means that whichever file is triggering that error (read the rest of the error message) has some output. The most common culprit is a space at the start of the file, before the `<?php` tag, but check for `echo` and other output keywords. Headers (including setting cookies) **must** be sent before any output.

---

From here on, this answer covers how you can implement the "refresh the page" part of the question. The code you provided doesn't really show how you do it right now, so this is all just how I'd recommend going about it.

Secondly, for refreshing the page, you will need to echo something at the end of `monitor.php` which your JS checks for. The easy way is to just echo a JS refresh:

```
echo '<script>window.location.reload();</script>';
```

but it's better to output some JSON which your `index.php` then checks for:

```
// monitor.php
echo json_encode(array('reload' => true));
```

---

```
// index.php
$('#src2').load('monitor.php?skill=<?php echo $skill;?>', function(response) {
    if (response.reload) window.location.reload();
}).fadeIn('slow');
```

One last note: you may find that `response` is just plain text inside the JS callback function - you may need to do this:

```
// index.php
$('#src2').load('monitor.php?skill=<?php echo $skill;?>', function(response) {
    response = $.parseJSON( response ); // convert response to a JS object
    if (response.reload) window.location.reload();
}).fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
ob_start()
```

before

```
session_start()
```

on each page. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Without looking at the code where you are setting the session, I do think your problem is there. You need to start the session before sending any data out to the browser.

Take a look at: http://php.net/session_start

**EDIT:**
Sorry, a bit quick, could it be that you send some data to the browser in the 'conn.php' file? Like a new line at the end of the file?